# Reevaluating a model-level query

Tags: django, django-models

In brief: A model's method performs a query (returning the output of objects.filter()), but when the objects' values are changed in the database, the results of objects.filter() don't update until I bounce the server.  How can I force the query to evaluate each time the method is called?

The details:

At the model level, I've defined a method to return all non-expired Announcement objects:

```
class AnnouncementManager(models.Manager):
    # this is the method
    def activeAnnouncements(self, expiry_time):
        activeAnnouncements = self.filter(expires_at__gt=expiry_time).all()
        return activeAnnouncements

class Announcement(models.Model):
    ...
    expires_at = models.DateTimeField("Expires", null=True)
    objects    = AnnouncementManager()
```

I call this from a view with:

```
activeAnnouncements = Announcement.objects.activeAnnouncements()
```

However, when an Announcement object's data is updated in the database (e.g. expires_at is changed), the query still reflects the old data until the server is bounced.  After reading http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated, I tried to force the query to reevalute by updating the method as follows:

```
def activeAnnouncements(self, expiry_time):
    # use boolean evaluation to force reevaluation of queryset
    if self.filter(expires_at__gt=expires):
        pass
    activeAnnouncements = self.filter(expires_at__gt=expiry_time).all()
    return activeAnnouncements
```

This had no effect.

Thanks for your help!

**Update:**

> Can you please show the full code of where you are calling it?

This is the view which calls it:

```
@never_cache
def front_page(request):
    '''
    Displays the current announcements
    '''

    announcements = ''
    activeAnnouncements = Announcement.objects.activeAnnouncements().order_by('-id')
    if not request.user.get_profile().admin:
        hide_before = request.user.get_profile().suppress_messages_before
        if hide_before is not None:
            activeAnnouncements = activeAnnouncements.filter(created_at__gt=hide_before)

    if activeAnnouncements.count() > 0:
        announcements = activeAnnouncements
    else:
        announcements = ""

    return render_to(
        request
        , "frontpage.html"
        , {
            'announcements' : announcements
    })
```

And here's the full version of the Announcement and AnnouncementManager models (excerpted above):

```
class AnnouncementManager(models.Manager):
    # Get all active announcements (i.e. ones that have not yet expired)
    def activeAnnouncements(self, expires=datetime.datetime.now()):
        activeAnnouncements = self.filter(expires_at__gt=expires).all()
        return activeAnnouncements

class Announcement(models.Model):
    text       = models.TextField()
    subject    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    expires_at = models.DateTimeField("Expires", null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField("Creation Time", auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="created_announcements")
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField("Update Time", auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="updated_announcements")
    objects    = AnnouncementManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subject
```

Comment: That query should already be evaluated each time. Can you please show the full code of where you are calling it?

Comment: Sure, @DanielRoseman, I've updated the information above to include this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha. The full version of the Manager method has a big difference from the one you originally posted, and it's there that the trouble is.

```
def activeAnnouncements(self, expires=datetime.datetime.now()):
```

This is one of the biggest Python gotchas: default function parameters are evaluated when the function is *defined*, not when it is called. So the default value for `expiry` will be set to whenever the server process was first started. Read [the effbot's explanation](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm) of the problem. (Note it's a Python problem, not anything to do with Django querysets.)

Instead, do this:

```
def activeAnnouncements(self, expires=None):
    if expires is None:
        expires = datetime.datetime.now()
    activeAnnouncements = self.filter(expires_at__gt=expires).all()
    return activeAnnouncements
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010317/django-queryset-custom-manager-refresh-caching) an answer to your question?

Comment: Hi @LaundroMat, I don't think it's the same thing.  In the question you link to, the data is being set when the model is instantiated rather than when the method is called.  In my question, the data is set within the method, which I think suggests a different issue.